# Java program skips an input?

Tags: java

**Hello,**

I was trying to build a simple calculator using basic Java code and understand OOP better, so, I wrote this:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter an operation: ");
        String opr;
        opr = input.nextLine();

        if(opr == "+") {
            System.out.println("Enter another Number: ");
            int num2 = input.nextInt();
            Operation op = new Operation(num1, num2);
            op.addition();
        } else if (opr == "-") {
            System.out.println("Enter another Number: ");
            int num2 = input.nextInt();
            Operation op = new Operation(num1, num2);
            op.subtraction();
        } else if (opr == "*") {
            System.out.println("Enter another Number: ");
            int num2 = input.nextInt();
            Operation op = new Operation(num1, num2);
            op.multiplication();
        } else if (opr == "/") {
            System.out.println("Enter another Number: ");
            int num2 = input.nextInt();
            Operation op = new Operation(num1, num2);
            op.division();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please, Enter a valid operation!");
        }
    }
}
```

and another Class for math operations:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Operation {

    static int Num1;
    static int Num2;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public Operation(int x, int y) {
        x = Num1;
        y = Num2;
    }

    public void addition() {

        System.out.println(Num1 + Num2);

    }

    public void subtraction() {

        System.out.println(Num1 - Num2);
    }

    public void multiplication() {

        System.out.println(Num1 * Num2);

    }

    public void division() {

        System.out.println(Num1 / Num2);

    }
}
```

but it doesn't take input for the operation, and it goes straight to the next line of code, like so:

```
Enter a number: 
4
Enter an operation: 
Please, Enter a valid operation!
```

Could anyone, please point my mistake?

Note: I'm a newbie in Java and programming in general. so, please don't mind me if my code isn't the best, I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you had a couple of problems. The nextLine() will return an empty line the first time since nextInt consumes the integer only after receiving a new line char but leaves the new line char in the buffer. Additionally the equals comparison needs to be using opr.equals("+") or a switch statement. And finally your Operation class constructor had the variable assignment backwards. I have also modified the Operation private member variables to follow standard naming conventions and scoping practices. You generally want to make member variables private since if not explicitly defined they will be protected. I would recommend using a good IDE since it can catch a lot of those errors for you, try using the free [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/). Here is an updated version of your code.

```java
public class Operation {
    private final int num1;
    private final int num2;

    public Operation(int num1, int num2) {
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

    public void addition() {

        System.out.println(num1 + num2);

    }

    public void subtraction() {

        System.out.println(num1 - num2);
    }

    public void multiplication() {

        System.out.println(num1 * num2);

    }

    public void division() {
        System.out.println(num1 / num2);
    }
}
```

And your main class

```java
public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter an operation: ");
        String opr = null;
        while(opr == null || opr.length() == 0){
            opr = input.nextLine();
        }

        switch (opr) {
            case "+": {
                System.out.println("Enter another Number: ");
                int num2 = input.nextInt();
                Operation op = new Operation(num1, num2);
                op.addition();
                break;
            }
            case "-": {
                System.out.println("Enter another Number: ");
                int num2 = input.nextInt();
                Operation op = new Operation(num1, num2);
                op.subtraction();
                break;
            }
            case "*": {
                System.out.println("Enter another Number: ");
                int num2 = input.nextInt();
                Operation op = new Operation(num1, num2);
                op.multiplication();
                break;
            }
            case "/": {
                System.out.println("Enter another Number: ");
                int num2 = input.nextInt();
                Operation op = new Operation(num1, num2);
                op.division();
                break;
            }
            default:
                System.out.println("Please, Enter a valid operation!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be noted that you made the attributes `private`, non-`static` (which makes a big digference with OOP) and camelCase that the code complies with the standardszconventions.

Comment: I can fully understand that. But I think you should explain that in your answer. Especially how you fixed the constructor(the OP asdigned the attributes to the parameters of the constructor which does absolutely nothing)

Comment: I agree I have updated the answer accordingly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Interesting points, now I know how much more I need to learn. But what do you mean the variable assignment was backward? And thank you for your answer.

Comment: Your original code did this x = Num1; Which was assigning the member variable to the constructor argument. Using your variable names it should have been Num1 = x;

Comment: Oh, ok got it. but I ran the code and now it doesn't skip the input but doesn't do math operations properly. it always prints 0 as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`input.next` 
rather than 
`input.nextLine`
 as  nextInt accepts a number and the new line character `\n`.
In the switch ts checking for the new line character.